# Python ImportError when calling Python script from Java

Tags: java, python, importerror

First off, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909210/call-python-from-java-code-using-jython-cause-error-importerror-no-module-name) that wasn't ever really resolved.

I have a Python script that I want to execute from within my Java code. When I run the Python script on its own, it works properly. When I try to execute it from a Java [process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), I get an ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "address_to_geocode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from omgeo import Geocoder
ImportError: No module named omgeo
```

Per a suggestion from the linked question, I appended a direct path to the module in my Python import section to make sure the interpreter knows where to look, yet it still won't work:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/omgeo')
from omgeo import Geocoder
```

My next move was to call the python script from a bash script (which again, works on its own), but when I call the bash script from Java, the same error persists.  The issue, therefore seems to be on Java's end. Here is my java code:

```
    Process p = runner.exec("python address_to_geocode.py");

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    String stdReader = null;
    //Read output of command:
    while((stdReader = stdInput.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(stdReader);
    }

    //Read any command errors:
    while((stdReader = stdError.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(stdReader);
    }
    p.waitFor();
```

Is there anything wrong with my Java code or is this a bug? I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hi, it seems to me you need give full path to python script at Process p = runner.exec("python address_to_geocode.py");

Comment: I have tested it in Windows Vista 32, jre1.8.0_20 and python 2.7.5 and it works alright with: final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "d:\\address_to_geocode.py");

Comment: @rafalopez79 using the following:

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python",absolute_file_path);
Process p = pb.start();

the error persists... full path and all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. It looks like `ProcessBuilder` requires the full path not only to the python file itself, but to python:

```
ProcessBuilder("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python",absolute_file_path);
```

This solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Find your python bin location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxhc.png)

```
 $ cat ~/.bash_profile
```

Java code

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/micklin/anaconda2/bin/python","sentiment.py",done.toString());
```

[code above is put in TweetFeeder.java so that .py file can be put under the project root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP3IW.png)